"Too few nodes" error in LTSpice
does anybody know how I can fix this error
I keep getting the error when I simulate my circuit


Here's the spice model :
https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2663#design-tools-simulation

You've provided the link to the TPS2663 SPICE model, but you have not provided your spice model. Could you have LTSpice dump the text file then [edit] your post to include it so we can see how it's connecting to the TPS2663? There have been cases where some companies provide both an encrypted version of the model and an unencrypted version and the encrypted version can lead to this problem.

JBH's hunch is correct.  TI's model for the TPS2663 is a PSpice encrypted model and can therefore only be used in PSpice.  You cannot use it in LTspice.

Trying to find an unencrypted model after the comment from Ste Kulov, I found this:

